# Why would Capistrano fail with: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, openssl, capistrano, encryption-symmetric

In effect, we have two clusters, each with two CentOS 7.5 servers. System 1 is a development cluster with a wildcard certificate; System 2 is a production cluster with non-wildcard certificate on the frontend server but a wildcard certificate on the backend server.

We are running a Ruby on Rails on Apache with Passenger and deploying with Capistrano. We are trying to deploy the symmetric-encryption gem using AWS Key Management Service (KMS) to store the Customer Master Key (https://rocketjob.github.io/symmetric-encryption/configuration.html).

After a bit of work, both servers in System 1 (development) deployed and operated successfully. We were able to deploy successfully to the backend server of System 2 (production) but the frontend--the one with with non-wildcard certificate--failed during the `deploy:assets:precompile` phase of the Capistrano deployment:

```
01 Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
      01 /var/www/web-2/html/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.89.1/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:299:in `start_session'
...
01 /var/www/web-2/html/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-kms-1.28.0/lib/aws-sdk-kms/client.rb:1375:in `decrypt'
      01 /var/www/web-2/html/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/symmetric-encryption-4.3.1/lib/symmetric_encryption/utils/aws.rb:56:in `block in decrypt'
      01 /var/www/web-2/html/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/symmetric-encryption-4.3.1/lib/symmetric_encryption/utils/aws.rb:129:in `auto_create_master_key'
      01 /var/www/web-2/html/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/symmetric-encryption-4.3.1/lib/symmetric_encryption/utils/aws.rb:55:in `decrypt'
      01 /var/www/web-2/html/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/symmetric-encryption-4.3.1/lib/symmetric_encryption/keystore/aws.rb:137:in `read'
      01 /var/www/web-2/html/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/symmetric-encryption-4.3.1/lib/symmetric_encryption/keystore.rb:168:in `read_key'
      01 /var/www/web-2/html/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/symmetric-encryption-4.3.1/lib/symmetric_encryption/cipher.rb:22:in `from_config'
      01 /var/www/web-2/html/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/symmetric-encryption-4.3.1/lib/symmetric_encryption/config.rb:87:in `block in ciphers'
```

FYI, running `openssl s_client -connect s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443` on each production server produces different results, with the frontend server throwing the error.

Here is the backend server with the wildcard cert:

```
-bash-4.2$  openssl s_client -connect s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = IE, O = Baltimore, OU = CyberTrust, CN = Baltimore CyberTrust Root
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Washington, L = Seattle, O = "Amazon.com, Inc.", CN = *.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=*.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
   i:/C=IE/O=Baltimore/OU=CyberTrust/CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
     --%<--snip-->%--
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=*.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3727 bytes and written 415 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: B001EA6EC9FC5049EEE85A13DA0373634992E8AB907E4558BE64F5A26055223D
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: DE8B5EBE0645974504E83FB6AE73CB54042EDA6B13FCC32A0B6C601EC2231E3627FE721ECE1F07CA48915D2A69195C67
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1581341714
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
closed
```

And here is the backend server with the non-wildcard cert:

```
-bash-4.2$  openssl s_client -connect s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=*.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
   i:/C=IE/O=Baltimore/OU=CyberTrust/CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
     --%<--snip-->%--
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=*.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3727 bytes and written 415 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 002173BC9539FF9A0CAEAF4EE3699102D638784A30F505AAE679F26E0DA22EA0
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 252EF43EC4EB107FA27702CA5EDBEE894F8BAB9FD7B326EB581F49A666F21988543B7F0EF185F2E7D4D13E7E052A8B98
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1581341716
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
closed
```

We thought there might have been an issue with our certificate chain but after reading  and following the instructions in https://medium.com/@superseb/get-your-certificate-chain-right-4b117a9c0fce, we confirmed that our certificate and certificate chain are OK:

```
-bash-4.2$ openssl verify company.net.crt
company.net.crt: OK

-bash-4.2$ openssl x509 -in company.net.crt -noout -issuer
issuer= /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2

-bash-4.2$ openssl x509 -noout -subject -in ca-bundle.crt
subject= /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2

-bash-4.2$ openssl verify -CAfile ca-bundle.crt company.net.crt
company.net.crt: OK
```

So, somehow we can get two different results from openssl, depending upon context.

In a stretch, we also tried initializing AWS with `Aws.use_bundled_cert!` as per https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2415#issuecomment-460998632 but that didn't help. I have seen references to performing the following command, but we have not tried that yet as we want to investigate this a bit more (and see if that is the consensus of the folks on this site):

```
curl -fsSL curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o "$(ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE')"
```

So given we only have a problem with the one system that does not use the wildcard certificate, it appears we have something misconfigured somewhere between our server, the symmetric-encryption gem, or AWS (either the KMS or CMS).

Obviously, we'd love a solution to our problem but even suggestions on how to diagnose it would be greatly appreciated. Note, this is the first time we are using AWS KMS (in addition to the symmetric-encryption gem).

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case it appears that the file `ca-bundle.crt` in `/etc/pki/tls/certs` had been stepped on. Actually, that file is a symlink which points to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem` and it was actually that file which had been munged. Fortunately, since we have several identical systems, we were able to copy over an uncorrupted `tls-ca-bundle.pem` and the openssl test works and Capistrano can complete its deploy. So it seems this was more of a system administration issue than a software development issue. I just happened that adding the symmetric-encryption gem with AWS KMS exposed the problem.